# Facebook friend suggestions

Tags: facebook

An ex of mine has joined Facebook yesterday and I have been informed of this and asked to make friend suggestions for him. I have had no contact with him for over 5 years and have deleted his home number years ago and also have now change my phone no. So how come Fbk connected him with me straightaway? Could it be that he viewed my profile after setting up his profile - which h has kept totally private. No details showing at all, no photos ,no friends, nothing on Timeline. Thanks.

Comment: This is an Off topic question. It looks more like a privacy issue other than a security issue. This might help: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61412/anonymity-on-facebook-how-do-they-suggest-people-i-should-know?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It can be that he viewed your page or that you have some mutual facebook friends. Like old highschool/college friends or other people.

Also the question you're asking is not relevant for this forum.